# Xamrin forms Display alert height

Tags: xamarin

bool install = await DisplayAlert("Version " + jsonVersion + " available", "New version of application available. Please, update for new features. \n" + " \n " + "What's new in this release:\n \n" + releaseNotes, "Install Now", "Later");

How can i manage the height of the alert.

Answer (score 0):

There is no customization for xamarin forms display alerts.  If you want a customization I think you have to use a DependencyService and call OS Alert. or use nuget like this.

https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup
[image]